# Accessing element in REST export view json response

Tags: 8

I have an API created from a REST export view, now im trying to do some behat test, but im getting some strange/different result when accessing an element in the json formatted response.

Using this method to evaluate if the expression is valid/invalid:

```
public function evaluate(Json $json, $expression)
{
    if ($this->evaluationMode === 'javascript') {
        $expression = str_replace('->', '.', $expression);
    }
    try {
        return $json->read($expression, $this->propertyAccessor);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Failed to evaluate expression "%s"', $expression), 0, $e);
    }
}
```

This is the output of a regular node/content when I access `node/1/?_format=json` and I was able to get the `nid` value by typing `nid[0].value`. This is enclosed in a curly braces and I believe its an [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-json-start-with/5034547#5034547).

```
{
    "nid": [
        {
            "value": 1
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

However, in my REST export view(path = `api/custom/1?_format=json`) json formatted response of a custom content type that I noticed, is enclosed in `[]`, I get this result:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "test",
        "title": "title"
    },
    ...
]
```

But I am not able to access either of the fields, tried `user_id` or `title`.

**Other examples** that is valid and invalid:

**VALID** by accessing `data.type`, displays `article`

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "article",
        "id": "123",
    ...
    }
}
```

**INVALID** expression, tried `id[0].value` or `id.value`

```
[
    {
        "id": [
            {
                "value": 398
            }
        ],
    ...
    }
]
```

[Parent issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560587/accessing-an-element-in-json-responsearray)

Comment: Yep so your custom views endpoint will be diffirent structure  from default node due to the way views encodes the data ... so could it be as simple as makeing new test for the endpoint and follow its new structure 
i allways just use json_decode / array_key_exist for this kindof thing